# DSPIC30F4011 - Pin labled as "Alternative", can I use it?

Tags: pic, output, pins

I am using a DSPIC30F4011 PIC ( [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70135c.pdf) ) to send commands to three devices (one Bluetooth, model RN42 and two LED Drivers, model TLC5947). In the data sheet for this PIC (on page 13), it has three output pins listed. One of these is listed as being "Alternate" Receive. I want to know whether I can also use this pin to command one of the three devices.

Comment: The U1ARX pin (alternate UART receive pin) is listed as an **INPUT** pin with a schmitt trigger CMOS level. The three **OUTPUT*** pins are designated  U1TX, U1ATX, U2TX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PIC has a lot more than three output pins, when you take into consideration that any GPIO pin (Ports B, C, D, E and F, not all full populated) can be configured as output pins.

Your RN42 Bluetooth module has a UART interface, so you would be using either sets of the UART1 pins (U1RX/U1TX, or U1ARX/U1ATX) to interface with that.

The TLC5947 LED drivers, on the other hand, use a synchronous serial interface: you send bits down one line (SIN), and a clock down the other (SCLK), and the bits are clocked into the driver on the rising edge of the clock.  It is sort of like an SPI interface, and some people have gotten it to work that way (Google "TLC5947 SPI") but since the TLC5947 lacks a chip select pin I don't recommend using the dsPICs SPI interface.

Instead you should use four of the GPIO pins mentioned earlier, two for each driver, and write a "bit-bang" driver to send the bits to the drivers along with a clock.  It's actually very straightforward, just Google "TLC5947 bitbang" and you will get lots of references.